# Script not inserted on page load

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, json

I am working on a mock class where I need to fake getting data out of a database and sending it within a `json array` to javascript. However, I can't get it to work, I've followed several tutorials and examples and it looks like I am missing something.

This is my code in the `CodeBehind` file:

```
public class Segment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int[,] GetAllSegments()
    {
        int[,] segments = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };

        return segments;
    }

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[,] allSegments = GetAllSegments();

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = serializer.Serialize(allSegments);
        string script = String.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\">var allSegments={0}</script>", json);
        this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", script, true);
    }
}
```

The script is never appearing, also I tried it with `RegisterStartupScript` but that doesn't work either...

In my HTML page I have included the following at the top: `<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="Dashboard.aspx.cs" %>`

Can anyone spot the issue(s)? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Does your code get executed?

Comment: Yes I debugged it, no errors get thrown. Not sure if my code gets executed, since nothing is happening.

Comment: put here what your are getting in script string

Comment: put debugger inside script and then check

Comment: and your code behind should be segment not dashboard

Comment: why dont you simply use a getJson method ?

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, how could I put the debugger inside the script?

Comment: @Jef after the start bracket of client Script

Comment: just type debugger @Jef

Comment: Still no errors getting thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, the last argument in `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method is named `addScriptTags` and since you have set it to `true`, you should remove the script tag and let C# add those tags for you:

```
    int[,] allSegments = GetAllSegments();

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = serializer.Serialize(allSegments);
    string script = String.Format("var allSegments={0};", json);
    this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", script, true);
```

or just set `addScriptTags` to `false`:

```
        int[,] allSegments = GetAllSegments();

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = serializer.Serialize(allSegments);
        string script = String.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\">var allSegments={0};</script>", json);
        this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", script, false);
```

The other minor change I have made is just to add the semicolon to the end of your js code.

Comment: Thanks for your input, tried both solutions, however it still does not seem to work. Just to be sure, there have to appear a script tag with  the `var allSegments...` code in my `Dashboard.aspx` file right?

Comment: @Jef: yeah that' right. I just copied your code and did the same as I have explained in my answer, get the view-source and it was there, and also checked `allSegments` in the console , have u checked the console?

Comment: Wow thats very strange, yes I have checked the console and source code multiple times.

Comment: @Jef: so I think there is also one point to consider, u have your onLoad in Segment.aspx page but u are looking for it in dashboard.aspx, it could be the problem! Have u checked that?

Comment: By the way, I just edited something in my HTML page and an error appeared in `Dashboard.aspx.designer.cs` an identifier was expected, the classname has dissapeared, has this something to do with my problem?

Comment: The `Page_Load` is in the Dashboard.aspx.cs page, is this my problem?

Comment: Would it be possible to upload your project somewhere and give me the link so I can download it? I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jef: yes I can do that, but before that, let's try to clarify some points? firstly what does `Segment` have to do with `Dashboard`. because it seems they are both aspx pages.

Comment: I have an html page called `Dashboard.aspx`, in that page I specified the codebehind to `Dashboard.aspx.cs`, in that file I have the class `Segment`.

Comment: have you tried moving your `Page_Load` code to the `Dashboard.aspx` code behind instead?

Comment: I did, lots of errors but found another error: `new-line-in-constant-error` in line `string script = String.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\">var allSegments={0};</script>", json);` however it worked in your code, why not in mine. By the way, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jef: try this `string script = String.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>var allSegments={0};</script>", json);` it should solve the problem.

Comment: Still nothing :s, I really do not understand this.

Comment: I think my Page_Load isn't getting called at all

Comment: @Jef: yes that's the reason. I still don't see, if you use `Segment` as a class and not as a Page, why it inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`.

Comment: I did not manage to get it working yet, however someone pointed out I should use IIS to run my application, so I am trying to set that up now.